# Can I have a document to setup Azure Devops Release pipeline to execute sql scripts on Onprime Oracle Database?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Our Project Code repository is on Azure Git Repository and Database is on On-premise Oracle database. We would like to setup a Azure Devops pipeline to execute committed SQL scripts on Onprime Oracle database.

Please let me know if you have any documentation that guide us to setup the pipeline. Appreciate your help in advance. Please let us know if any details are required from our end. Thanks.

I tried executing Release pipeline with by creating a task with "Run Oracle Database Scripts". Though we have Active agent up and running with having Oracle client installed and SQLplus along, the pipeline is getting failed showing "No agent found in pool plsql which satisfies the specified demands: sqlplus.exe ".

When we try running script(s) on Sqlplus on same machine manually, it is getting completed without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to your statement, you run the release pipeline on the self-hosted agent which installed on yourself machine (we can call it **agent machine**).

Ensure you have completed the following things before running the **Run Oracle Database Scripts** task in your release pipeline:

- **`Sqlplus.exe`** must have been installed and added to system environment **`PATH`** on the agent machine so that it can be available on the machine.
- On Azure DevOps, open the agent pool where the self-hosted agent is in. Go to **Agents** tab, find and open (click) the self-hosted agent you use to run the release pipeline. On the **Capabilities** tab, add a User-defined capability. The name of the capability is "**`sqlplus.exe`**", the value can be empty or any key (such as the version number of **`sqlplus.exe`**).
  [image]

For more details, see the extension "[**Run Oracle Database Scripts**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liquorichris.run-oracle-scripts&ssr=false#overview)".
[image]